# split(" ") na String " Java Essencial " gera 3 tokens. Por quê?

Tags: java

A idéia era separar as palavras dos espaços em branco. Segue o seguinte código.

```
String s = " Java Essencial ";


String[] ss = s.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("[" + i + "] " + ss[i]);
}
```

Como se vê no resultado, temos três tokens. O correto não seria ter 2 tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem espaços no início e final da `String`. Para conseguir o resultado que você deseja (No caso 2 pedaços) você deve utilizar o método `trim` antes de realizar o `split`:

```
String[] ss = s.trim().split(" ");
```

Isso irá limpar os espaços no início e final da `String`, garantindo o resultado desejado.

Note também que você terá problemas se houver mais de um espaço separando as palavras. Neste caso, além do `trim()` você pode utilizar uma expressão regular em conjunto com o `replaceAll()` para substituir dois ou mais espaços por apenas um. A expressão seria `[ ]{2,}` e substituindo no seu código teríamos:

```
String[] ss = s.replaceAll("[ ]{2,}", " ").trim().split(" ");
```

> [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())
>
> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a cópia da string, omitindo os espaços em branco no início e final.

---

> [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Em tradução livre:

> Substitui cada substring da string que combine com a expressão regular dada pela substituição dada.